# How do I set tools on phone screen according to android phone height and width?

Tags: android

I am new to Android layout development and have been tasked with designing and developing an application.

I have created the absolute layout but it is giving me different ways to output in different android phone versions. For example, when I set the `EditText`, `Button`, `TextView` etc. in my phone, I get a perfect view but when it runs on the client’s phone it looks very bad.

It is very important for me to set the same view for different phones. I would appreciate if someone can provide code examples for controls in absolute layout so I can get the same output on all phones and set height and width so that they are same in phones with different resolutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `AbsoluteLayout` you're already doing it wrong. :) It's deprecated precisely because it makes working with multiple screen sizes unnecessarily difficult, just as you've observed.

See [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for a better approach. `RelativeLayout` lets you specify your layout in terms of rules, e.g. "Place view A along the top of the screen and stretch it to fill the full screen width. Place view B along the left edge below view A and let it be as tall as it needs to be to fit its content."

You should also reference the link posted in yogsma's answer for more general advice.